# TFS Build looking for wrong branch of source

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfsbuild

Have a CI build set up in a very simple solution (MVC webapp, Service, MSTest project)

The build shows orange with the following:

> Handle MSTest Exception  There is no working folder mapping for
>   /Heartbeat/Source/BvtAutomation/Local.testsettings

Now, here's the kicker, that is not the source branch being built, it is another project altogether! I cannot find any reference to it in the build definition or anywhere in my solution (WinGrep .. the whole nine yards!)

Anyone seen anything similar to this or have a suggestion as to what I might try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TFS2010 when building with DefaultTemplate.xaml, the test files to run are not specified relatively to the mapped workspace, but instead by their complete path from Source Control.

So to fix the issue:

1. Edit your build definition
2. Go to the *Process* tab
3. In the *2. Basic* section, select *Automated Tests* and click the *...* button to edit the test settings.
4. In the *Automated Tests* dialog, browse for the .testsettings file in the branch you're building.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: select build definition in the Team Explorer, right-click -> Edit build definition. On the 'Workspace' tab you can configure sources to be got to the build machine. HTH

Comment: the question refers to Local.testsettings which implies the build is looking for the test project. the other answer is correct.